# Why should the name of array be same as that of the JsonObject?

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

Using this repository :https://github.com/dds861/Retrofit2
And Following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@dds861/json-parsing-using-retrofit-and-recycleview-2300d9fdcf15
The code works fine out of the box but it gives me a null pointer exception if i changed the name of the array returned by the JsonResponse Class.
This is the response returned by Json:

```
{ "android": [ { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" }, { "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4" }, { "ver": "2.0 - 2.1", "name": "Eclair", "api": "API level 5 - 7" }, { "ver": "2.2", "name": "Froyo", "api": "API level 8" }, { "ver": "2.3", "name": "Gingerbread", "api": "API level 9 - 10" }, { "ver": "3.0 - 3.2", "name": "Honeycomb", "api": "API level 11 - 13" }, { "ver": "4.0", "name": "Ice Cream Sandwich", "api": "API level 14 - 15" }, { "ver": "4.1 - 4.3", "name": "JellyBean", "api": "API level 16 - 18" }, { "ver": "4.4", "name": "KitKat", "api": "API level 19" }, { "ver": "5.0 - 5.1", "name": "Lollipop", "api": "API level 21 - 22" }, { "ver": "6.0", "name": "Marshmallow", "api": "API level 23" }, { "ver": "7.0 - 7.1", "name": "Nougat", "api": "API level 24 - 25" } ] }
```

The array name inside JsonResponse class is android which is same as name of the object in the response.If I change it to something like androids,it crashes. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @SerializedName annotation to give your variable a different name

For Example -

```
public class POJOClass {

    @SerializedName("android") //here use name same as in json to let them map.
    private ArrayList androidList; //use name as you want here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the array name in your pojo class but you should keep the serialized name to android.

Comment: The example doesnt seem to use serialization.

Comment: you can add if you want to change the name of array also this will help you in case of enabling progaurd after abfuscating code. By specifying **bold**@SerializedName, GSON will not look in json based on variable name & will just use specified **bold**@SerializedName

Answer (score 1):

If you want have a different name in your POJO object you need to use [@SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

For example, in your case you need do something like this:

```
public class POJOClass {

    //...

    @SerializedName("android")
    private ArrayList androids;

    //...

}
```

Now you can have an arrayList with the name that you want. With this annotation you link the element in the json with your variable.